# Which data is stored in Power BI - the one after query or the one after modelling?

Tags: powerbi

In Power BI first we get source data. And then we add multiple query steps to filter data/remove column/etc. Then we add relations and model the data.

We can have calculated columns that are stored in the data. And measures that are not stored in the data but calculated on the fly.

Which data is stored in Power BI - the one after query or the one after modelling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power BI has 3 connection types for data access. They are import, direct query and live connections.
If we use import method as a connection type, data imported into Power bi file using Power BI desktop. So all the data always stays in disk. When query or refresh, data stays in computer memory.This data we can use to query and modeling. After work, we save the Power BI file it will save as file with .pbix extension. Data compressed and stored inside this file.

in direct query mode , data stays in remote location and we can connect data. each time we refresh or make change in slicer request goes to data source and bring back data to power bi. In this method, we can't access data but we can create data model.

live connection is another method. It only support for few data sources. In this method, data not stored in computer memory and can't create data model using Power BI desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI is very well [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/). Many of the questions you've recently asked are answered in that resource, so please take a look. I get the feeling that you are using this community because you don't want to read the manual. I strongly suggest you take a look at the documentation, because everything we write in answer to your questions has already been written and documented, and SO is not meant to be a shadow user guide for well documented systems.

Depending on the data source you use in Power BI Desktop, Power BI supports query folding, which will do as much processing of the data at the source (for example SQL Server).

If query folding is not possible because the source does not support it, then the source data is loaded before the query steps are applied.

Read more about query folding here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/power-query-folding

When you perform additional modelling after the Power Queries are loaded, i.e. creating tables with DAX, adding columns, etc., these will be performed when the PBIX file is published to the Power BI service, and they will be performed each time the data is refreshed with the data gateway.

Comment: When the report is published to power bi service and user does a refresh (source is sql server db), then 1st data is pulled from the database and then it is modelled. I want to ask - does power bi service storage store the data retrieved by the query editor's query to the db or the data after it is modelled?

Comment: The user cannot trigger a refresh from the source. That's not how it works. As someone already explained in one of your other questions, data refresh is performed only via the data gateway. By definition that means that the queries are refreshed in the service, and the service also re-calculates any DAX. But that is not done when an individual user accesses a report, only when the data is refreshed (which the end consumer cannot do).

Comment: Sorry I meant to ask - when the user responsible for the dataset does the refresh, then  does power bi service storage store the data retrieved by the query editor's query to the db or the data after it is modelled?

Comment: The data is pulled from the sources and stored in the Power BI service. The DAX runs on the data that the queries have retrieved. How exactly the Service stores the data and which parts of the DAX are calculated at what point in time is not really relevant, is it? What drives this question?

Comment: Wondering if it would affect the time to load report. Example to pull the data out from storage, model and display the report. Where as if the data were stored after modelling then that time would be saved?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. When the data is refreshed, it goes into the model and the model DAX is performed. THEN you publish the report PBIX to the service, with all the data in the PBIX and the report is consumed in the browser. When the data is refreshed in the Service, that refresh runs via the gateway on a schedule and it doesn't matter how long the refresh takes or in which order the DAX is calculated. It does not dramatically affect the timing of anything. When the refresh is complete, the report shows the new data. There is no time anywhere to be saved.

Comment: I have read that report data (and calculated coloumns) are stored in the pbix file, and that the DAX are calculated on the fly (via processor[CPU])

Comment: Sorry, I'm really getting confused about what you are asking and what has been answered, and I find the whole discussion quite pointless. Data is loaded into the PBIX with the query. Modelling takes place after the data load, but that is still stored in the PBIX. Measures are stored in the PBIX, but re-calculated when the filters are changed on the fly. That's in Power BI Desktop. Once the report is published into the Service, at which point all the data in the PBIX goes online, the data will change with a data refresh (via the gateway) at which time the model is getting recalculated, too.